# Do I need loaders in Angular application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

Loaders can be used in Webpack configuration. It can be `file-loader`, `html-loader`, `css-loader`, `json-loader`, `raw-loader`, `style-loader`, `to-string-loader`, `url-loader`, `awesome-typescript-loader`.

Does Angular know about loaders without explicit Webpack configuration? Maybe it uses some internal ones under the hood?

Currently I have an Angular 6 enterprise application with all those loaders. But are they required? I mean that loaders should be attached using `webpack.config.json`. But I don't have any Webpack configuration in the project. Only short `tsconfig.webpack.json`, that configures more TS than Webpack.
Can it be that -  in my case - loaders are just redundant dependencies left after previous migrations?

Comment: If you uninstall them, does anything break?

Comment: Application is quite complicated, and regressions may be not visible from the first glance. But may be in case of uninstalling all of them it could be faster ). Anyway it is still not clear for me if Angular uses installed loaders without explicit webpack config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `angular-cli` then there are no need for them. `angular-cli` handles webpack configuration for you and bundled with every loader you will ever need so just remove them will be fine.

[source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/package.json)

Comment: So under the hood angular-cli uses the same loaders as internal dependencies, right? And installed ones are not being used at all?

Comment: @AlexVovchuk yes. unless you use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack

Comment: Looks reasonable, thanks. But  one more concern: I place angular-cli to dev-dependencios, but loaders are required in main dependencies. How does it work in this case?

Comment: @AlexVovchuk seems like you have no idea about dep and devDep. You should definitely read something about it. In this case, everything in both dep and devDep field are installed locally, and their deps. As its name says, devDep are only installed when you are developing that package

Comment: yes, and we don't get dev-dependencies in final bundle, but dependencies go there. Don't we need loaders in final bundle?

Comment: You don't. Loaders only work in build time like a compiler plugin.